# Migrate SQL Server 2008 Analysis database to 2012 AS database along with data level security defined in current production cube

Tags: sql-server-2008, migration, sql-server-2012, ssas

Migrate SQL Server 2008 Analysis database to 2012 AS database along with data level security defined in current production cube

I want to migrate Analysis Services 2008 database to 2012 AS database along with dimension data security defined in current production cube

Note: Only Production environment have security, while no security is defined in development environment

Potential Approach:

1. Using Synchronization Wizard: Gives me error : "The OLAP element at line1 can not appear under envelope......" and this is because Synchronization works only for same version and in my case, there are different versions of SQL (SQL Server 2008 and 2012)
2. Using Visual studio conversion wizard - Convert SQL Server 2008 AS project to 2012 and then process cube, so I can get the cube working but then how can I get data level security since 100's of dimension data security is defined in production Cube, so how can I migrate that across
3. Script out XMLA and deploy cube - But then again having issues with how can i script SSAS security
4. Would taking backup of SSAS 2008 database and restore to SSAS 2012 will help ?

Any suggestions would be appreciated

Thanks,

Mihir

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the issue is that you only defined the security online in the running Analysis Services database and not in the project files, you could proceed as follows:

In Visual Studio, select File/New/Project/Business Intelligence projects/Import Analysis Services Database, and configure the location where you want to save the project. Then, when you click on OK, a wizard starts that lets you connect to a running AS database, a copy of which is then saved as a new project in your local environment. This should contain all definitions exactly as they are in the running database.

If it would be better to do this in VS2008 (old version) and then upgrade, or directly downloading it in VS2010, I am not sure, you will have to try that.

Comment: Thanks Frank, will try and let you know

Answer (score 0):

I have taken backup from current production system (SQL Server 2008) and then restored on SQL Server 2012 server.

Then changed connection string on AS database.

Further converted SQL 2008 solution to SQL 2012 solution using Visual Studio

And then process existing cubes in Dev environment

And now I will synchronize UAT from Dev environment without security, so I would have migrated metadata and data into my new AS 2012 cube

I will update my findings soon

Thanks,
Mihir